# how to use EGOPhotoViewer in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, github

i want to use EGOphotoviewer in my app such like that when user press button, instead of loading tableView of rootviewController, it just navigate to photos, can anyone help me ? 
[image]

here i don t want tableView i just need a button for photos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demo project is using a UITableViewController subclass called rootViewController and on the didSelect method it is just initializing the EGOPhotoViewerController and pushing it. All you need to do is instead of using a UTableViewController subclass, use a UIViewController subclass, add a button inside its view, create an action for that button, and inside the action, do the exact same thing ::

```
MyPhoto *photo = [[MyPhoto alloc] initWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/66601193/cactus.jpg"] name:@" laksd;lkas;dlkaslkd ;a"];
MyPhoto *photo2 = [[MyPhoto alloc] initWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/twitter_production/profile_images/425948730/DF-Star-Logo.png"] name:@"lskdjf lksjdhfk jsdfh ksjdhf sjdhf ksjdhf ksdjfh ksdjh skdjfh skdfjh "];
MyPhotoSource *source = [[MyPhotoSource alloc] initWithPhotos:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:photo, photo2, photo, photo2, photo, photo2, photo, photo2, nil]];

EGOPhotoViewController *photoController = [[EGOPhotoViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:source];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:photoController animated:YES];

[photoController release];
[photo release];
[photo2 release];
[source release];
```

And you'll get what you want.

Hope this helps

Comment: i am sucessful in customizing this sample but the problem is my back button is not displaying on detailView as well as on thumbView

Comment: Did you get any solution for displaying back button? I am also facing same problem.